# Alternative useState in react-native class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i'm aware i cant use `useState` in class components, but there's this tutorial i'm trying to relpicate in my App. They used a functional component unlike me.

Their App.js in the [tutorial](https://github.com/mdrajibsk8/React-Native-Push-Notification-Firebase7) is like this:

```
const App = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
    fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification);
    localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotification)
  },[])


  const onRegister = (token) => {
    console.log("[App] Token", token);
  }

  const onNotification = (notify) => {
    // console.log("[App] onNotification", notify);
    const options = {
      soundName: 'default',
      playSound: true,
    }

    localNotificationService.showNotification(
      0,
      notify.notification.title,
      notify.notification.body,
      notify,
      options,
    )
  }

  const onOpenNotification = async (notify) => {
  
    console.log('notify', notify);
  }
```

So basically, `const onOpenNotification`, `const onRegister`, `const onNotification` are called in another file imported into App.js. I tried adding them in my App.js like :

```
class App extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
    fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification);
    localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotification)
    const onRegister = (token) => {
      console.log("[App] Token", token);
    }
  
    const onNotification = (notify) => {
      // console.log("[App] onNotification", notify);
      const options = {
        soundName: 'default',
        playSound: true,
      }
  
      localNotificationService.showNotification(
        0,
        notify.notification.title,
        notify.notification.body,
        notify,
        options,
      )
    }
  
    const onOpenNotification = async (notify) => {
    
      console.log('notify', notify);
    }
  }
}
```

My console.log shows these errors:

```
 LOG  [FCMService] getInitialNotification getInitialNotification null
 LOG  [LocalNotificationService] onRegister: {"os": "android", "token": "emA0hq4KCMq0j:APA91bEWbOUXjxdIs_s2ksSbjwxhdMVfr35y9sZBUIYX72Q9obU7daQw4zI-a0qn6KsvxWvGtQoEdPlTq5l98trb-yhmtARDcliqAayi_r0K8f_"}
 LOG  [FCMService] getToken Rejected [TypeError: onRegister is not a function. (In 'onRegister(fcmToken)', 'onRegister' is undefined)]
```

I'm guessing that's because the `const functions()` are not properly structured, Whats the best way to replicate this tutorial, preferably if I don't have to change to a functional component
I don't think I would be able to put all the information you might need to help here, but I would appreciate if you could take some time to see [how the 2 imported files](https://github.com/mdrajibsk8/React-Native-Push-Notification-Firebase7/tree/master/app/Notification) I talked about are structured and how they call the `const onRegister` in App.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Updated Code

Try moving the methods to class level.

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
        fcmService.register(this.onRegister, this.onNotification, this.onOpenNotification);
        localNotificationService.configure(this.onOpenNotification)
    }

    onRegister = (token) => {
      console.log("[App] Token", token);
    }

    onNotification = (notify) => {
      // console.log("[App] onNotification", notify);
      const options = {
          soundName: 'default',
          playSound: true,
      }

      localNotificationService.showNotification(0,notify.notification.title,
            notify.notification.body, notify, options,)
    }

    onOpenNotification = async (notify) => {
        console.log('notify', notify);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your contribution. However, don't think I can have `const` on class level like that, VSCode throws an error

Comment: @kunlee Sorry for the trouble. I've updated the code.